# ListLinePlot: different colors for list range

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a nested list using `ListLinePlot` and to set different colors according to the length of the nested lists, e.g.:

```
data={{0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 1.25, 1., 1.5, 1., 1.5, 0.5, 1., 1., 1.5, 
  0.5, 1., 1., 1., 1.25, 1.25, 1., 1., 1.25, 1.25, 1.75, 1.75, 1.25, 
  1.25, 1., 1., 0.5, 0.5}, {0.25, 0.75, 1., 1., 0.5, 1., 0.5, 0.5, 
  0.75, 0.5, 0.75, 1.25, 0.75, 0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.75, 1.25, 0.5, 1., 
  0.5, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.25, 1.25, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 
  0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.5, 1., 0., 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
  0.75, 0.75, 1., 1., 0.5, 0.5}, {0.25, 0.5, 0., 0., 0.25, 0.5, 
  0.}, {0.5, 0., 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5}};

ListLinePlot[Flatten[data], PlotRange -> All]
```

so that each each of the nested lists has its own color:

```
color1range = Length[data[[1]]];
color2range = Length[data[[2]]];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming (from your use of `Flatten`) that you want all the sublists to be plotted sequentially, rather than stacked on top of each other. One way to achieve this is the following:

```
l = Accumulate[Join[{0}, Length /@ data]];
ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[{l[[#2[[1]]]] + #2[[2]], #1} &, data, {2}]]
```

which gives

[image]

(Basically, you have to build in the correct `x`-coordinate to your data.) You can then manipulate the colours of each sublist with `PlotStyle` (which I'll get to below).

One problem with this plot is that the lines don't join up. A more convoluted version of the same approach (which indexes the `Flatten`ed data and then partitions it back into the correct form) can fix this:

```
l = Length /@ data
data2 = MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, Flatten[data]]
ind = Join[{1}, Accumulate[l]]
data3 = Table[data2[[ind[[j]] ;; ind[[j + 1]]]], {j, Length[ind] - 1}]

ListLinePlot[data3, PlotRange -> All]
```

which gives you

[image]

(I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do that. `Partition` for ragged arrays would help, but I think I'm missing something simple.)

Finally, if you want to colour to depend on the length of the sublist you could do:

```
l = Length /@ data;    
ListLinePlot[data3, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> (Hue[#/Max[l], 0.75, 0.75] & /@ l)]
```

[image]

Comment: There is [``Internal`PartitionRagged``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83124/22013)

Comment: @corey979 Thanks! I can't remember how many times I've wished I had something like that.

Answer (score 3):

```
colors = ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; Length@data]];
mesh = Accumulate[Length /@ data];

llp = ListLinePlot[Flatten@data, BaseStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True,
 MeshShading -> colors, MeshStyle -> None, Mesh -> {mesh}]
```

[image]

```
rectangles = Thread/@Thread[{Partition[Prepend[mesh, 0], 2, 1], {0, Max[data]}}, List, 1];

Show[llp, GridLines -> {mesh, None}, 
  Epilog -> ({Opacity[.2], #, Rectangle @@ #2} & @@@ Transpose[{colors, rectangles}])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it:

```
ListLinePlot[Block[{i = 1}, Map[{i++, #} &, data, {2}]]]
```

[image]

To get rid of the gaps (and to show another method)

```
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; Length@data]];

clist = Most @ Flatten @ MapThread[ConstantArray, {colors, List@*Length /@ data}];

par = Partition[#, 2, 1]& @ Transpose[{Range@Length@#, #}] &[Flatten @ data];

Graphics[
 Transpose[{clist, Map[Line] @ par}],
 Axes -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ListPlot[data,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Orange}]
```